# Call variable inside array element

Tags: php, arrays, variables, string-interpolation

Is it possible to read array element using variable?
I'd like to set $vid in one place depending on the configuration, and then use multiple times i.e. $detailrow["customfields1"];
I want to do this:

```
$vid = 1;
$detailrow["customfields$vid"];
```

But no response.

Tried:

```
$detailrow["customfields{$vid}"];
$detailrow['customfields'.$vid];
```

but result is the same.

Comment: The last one should work. How do you initialize your array?

Comment: What are the results? Your tries look perfectly valid to me

Comment: Its working [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RpfBE3)

Comment: How about an intermediate step like `$newKey = "customfields" . $vid` and then `$detailrow[$newKey]`?

Comment: use print_r() to check whether there is value associated to the key or not.I think that could be the problem

Comment: All three of your tried methods ought to work fine. Check your raw data.

Comment: Ok, it was array depth misunderstanding. Works fine now.

Thanks for quick replies!

Comment: what u tried is correct but does your array have the key??just see that by using `print_r`

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do this:

```
$tmp=array("name" => "foo", "bar" => "name", "field1" => "value1");
```

You could then do sth. like

```
echo $tmp["name"];
```

will print 'foo'

```
echo $tmp[$tmp["bar"]];
```

will also print 'foo'

Or

```
$i=1;
echo $tmp["field".$i]
```

will print 'value1'

Answer (score 0):

i have tested your code and its working

```
<?php
 $vid = 1;
 $detailrow["customfields1"]="rajeev";
 echo $detailrow["customfields$vid"];

?>
```